# Error 10051 while trying to connect socket

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking

I recently built a socket-server chat in **linux**.

When I try to connect my **windows 8.1** main computer (Both under the same subnet), i get an:

```
[Errno 10051]: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
```

Code:

```
import socket
import datetime 
import getpass          # Get username
import sys
import thread
import select

def client():

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8856))
sock.connect(("192.168.1.17", 23657))
sock.send(getpass.getuser()+"[$ID$]4sthg")

socket_list = [sys.stdin, sock]
partner = raw_input("Chat partner: ")

while 1:
    # Get the list sockets which are readable
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets =       select.select(socket_list , [], [])
    for sock_index in read_sockets:
        # incoming message from remote server
        if sock_index == sock:
            data = sock_index.recv(4096)
            if not data :
                print '\nDisconnected from chat server'
                sys.exit()
            else :
                #print data
                sys.stdout.write(data)
        # user entered a message
        else:
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            sock.send(partner + "|" + msg)

def get_time():
    return datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S')

def main():
    client()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried "ping" to my laptop address, and it worked well. also added a rule in my linux firewall, declares that every packet comes from my windows computer is allowed.

Any idea why it happens?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Show your code. Most likely the address is not translated properly from string to network byte order integer form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8856))
```

is wrong - you are binding to the ***`loopback`*** virtual interface, thus only allowing local (same machine) peers to talk to you.

In fact, when you connect out, i.e. act as a normal TCP client, you should not bind the local end of the socket at all . Kernel TCP/IP stack will assign an ***`ephemeral port`*** to the socket, and the routing table will dictate what network interface to use for outgoing connection.

On the same note, the **`SO_REUSEADDR`** option is only needed for listening servers:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Remove these two lines and retry.