# Python socket server and client not working over different pcs

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to make a chat program with a server and clients. When you run the server and client script on the same pc, it appears to be working, but when you run the server script and the client script on different pcs, the client script throws one of the following errors when trying to connect to the server address:

```py
WinError[10061]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 
WinError[10051]: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
socket.timeout
```

I have tried changing disabling my firewall for the server pc, binding the server to the ip "0.0.0.0" and my actual ipv4 address, and reading other stackoverflow posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462729/error-10051-while-trying-to-connect-socket), but to no avail. The server client system does work if another pc is the server (with its firewall enabled) while my main pc is the client, but it isn't working the other way around

Server Code:

```py
import socket
import threading
import pickle

class Server:
    """Represents a server which clients can connect to and send messages to"""
    def __init__(self, port=5050, header=1048, server_pass="", format_="utf-8"):
        """
        :param port: int
        :param header: int
        :param format: str
        """
        self.PORT = port
        self.HEADER = header
        self.SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        self.ADDR = ("0.0.0.0", self.PORT) # the ip address here has also been replaced with my actual ipv4 address
        print (self.ADDR)
        self.server_password = server_pass
        self.FORMAT = format_
        self.DISCONNECT_MSG = "!DISCONNECT".encode(self.FORMAT)
        self.started = False
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

        # {"username": [conn, messages]}
        self.clients = {}
        # ordered messages
        self.messages = []
        self.banned_ips = []

        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def bind_server(self):
        """
        Attempts to bind the server to self.ADDR, returns true if binding wsa successful
        :returns: bool
        """
        try:
            self.server.bind(self.ADDR)
            return True

        except:
            return False

    def start(self):
        """
        Starts the server
        :returns: None
        """
        self.started = True

        try:
            self.server.listen(5)

        except:
            return None

        print ("server has started")

        # Wait for any incoming connections, and handle that connection
        while True:
            try:
                conn, addr = self.server.accept()

            except OSError as e:
                print (f"OSError: {str(e)}")
                break

            # This part never gets ran, because client isn't able to join server
            client_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
            client_thread.setDaemon(True)
            client_thread.start()

        self.close()

    def handle_client(self, conn, addr):
        print (f"connection from {str(addr)}")
        # code to handle client

    def close(self):
        print ("server closed")
        self.server.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    bound = server.bind_server()
    print (bound)
    server.start()
```

Client code:

```py
import socket
import threading
import pickle
from _pickle import UnpicklingError

class Client:
    """Represents a client which can join and send messages to a Server"""
    def __init__(self, username, server_ip, port=5050, header=1048, format_="utf-8", server_pass=""):
        """
        :param port: int
        :param header: int
        :param format_: str
        """
        self.PORT = port
        self.HEADER = header
        self.FORMAT = format_
        self.SERVER = server_ip
        self.DISCONNECT_MSG = "!DISCONNECT"

        self.server_password = server_pass
        self.ADDR = (self.SERVER, self.PORT)
        self.username = username
        self.connected = False

        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.clients = {}
        self.messages = []

    def join_server(self):
        """
        Connects the client to the server
        :returns: bool
        """

        self.client.settimeout(20)

        try:
            self.client.connect(self.ADDR) # Exception is being thrown here

        except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
            return self.connected

        except socket.timeout:
            print ("timed out :/")
            return self.connected

        except WindowsError as e:
            if e.winerror == 10060:
                print ("couldn't connect to server because it took too long to respond or it has failed to respond")
            elif e.winerror == 10051:
                print ("network is unreachable")

            return self.connected

        else:
            self.client.settimeout(None)

        # Start receiving any new clients or new client messages
        receive_clients_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_clients)
        receive_clients_thread.start()

        self.connected = True
        self.send_message(self.username)
        self.send_message(self.server_password)

        return self.connected

    def receive_clients(self):
        # code to receive clients from server
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = input("Username: ")
    server_pass = input("Server password: ")
    server_ip = "IPV4" # IPv4 address goes here

    client = Client(username, server_ip, server_pass=server_pass)
    client.join_server()

    while client.connected:
        message = input(f"{client.username}: ")
        client.send_message(message)

        if message == "q":
            break

    print ("not connected")
    if client.connected:
        client.close()
```

There is more code in both classes, but I believe that I have showed enough code so that the question can be answered.

Comment: you remembered to put the right address in the client, right?

Comment: @user253751 as in the ipv4 address ? Well yes, I have pinged it from the server ip.

Comment: did you put the ip address which ifconfig command returns, can you write the ip here or at least first 6 digits? are the both computers in the same local network?

Comment: I have found the answer to my question, as you can see in the last portion of my post, I did have the wrong ip address

Comment: please move the last part and to a self-answer or delete the post.